# Spontanous emission Hamiltonian model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, quantum-optics, models, open-quantum-systems

I am looking for a clear (and not too long) model of spontaneous emission, for an atom modeled by a two level system in a cavity where the field is multimode

I am looking for model bases on Hamiltonian interaction. Indeed, what I know for now is an open system effective evolution (a Lindblad master equation).

Things that I would like to really understand with this model for example are the fact that my atom can radiate in other frequencies than its bare frequency $\omega_0$.

Comment: Look up the [Caldeira-Leggett model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_dissipation).

Comment: Did you see the [Jaynes-Cummings model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaynes%E2%80%93Cummings_model) already?

Comment: @ThomasFritsch yes I know the Jaynes-Cummings model ! But only for a monomode field (maybe you are thinking about generalisations ?)

Comment: Ah sorry. I missed your "multimode".

Comment: @ThomasFritsch actually I could start to see it with a monomode field. But even with J.C Hamiltonian I am not sure to understand spontaneous emission. Indeed, if I assume that the field has same frequency than the qubit for example I will just have periodic oscillations (sinusoidal if the field is in a number mode, and collapse and revival if the field is in a coherent state, but still). So lets assume for simplicity first I have a monomode field, how can I understand properly spontaneous emission with J.C ?

Comment: The keyword to search for here is Wigner-Weisskopf (or Weisskopf-Wigner).